# How to ftp multiple files using a shell script

Tags: unix, ftp

I am trying to ftp multiple files from one machine to another using a shell script. Below is my script:

```
ftp -nv <<EOF
open home.machine.com
user remote monday
binary
mput *.txt
bye
<<EOF
```

Now, the problem is, it hangs in between, but when I try each and every command on the command prompt. After I execute `mput *.txt`, it asks for confirmation for each and every file. When I enter `yes` then it moves on to the next file, and asks again.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please remove '<<' chars in the beginning of last line cause it starts new block and commands after will be ommited by shell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried something like this:

```
prompt
mput *.txt
```

The [`prompt`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ftp) command closed the user interaction, and then it worked properly.

Answer (score 3):

From the manual:

> `-i`    Turns off interactive prompting during multiple file transfers.

Comment: i tried like `mput -i *.txt`, but that also didn't worked..am i using incorrectly.. when i tried this.. only 2-3 files gets ftp rest doesn't...

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code snippet, it should be like this:

```
ftp -inv <<EOF
open home.machine.com
user remote monday
binary
mput *.txt
bye
<<EOF
```

Notice the inclusion of '-i' in the `ftp` arguments.

Also, it is not advisable to use `mput` since it will be difficult to track errors compared to transferring files individually.

Answer (score 0):

```
ftp -n ftp.test.com <<+
user ftpUser  password 
cd  local_dir/
lcd  remote_dir/
mget *.*
mdelete *.*
quit
bye
+
```